# Stretchy Layout not working with child view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, snapkit

I'm trying to follow the example described here for making a stretchy layout which includes a `UIImageView` and `UIScrollView`. https://github.com/TwoLivesLeft/StretchyLayout/tree/Step-6

The only difference is that I replace the `UILabel` used in the example with the view of a child `UIViewController` which itself contains a `UICollectionView`. This is how my layout looks - the blue items are the `UICollectionViewCell`.[image]

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class HomeController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
private let imageView = UIImageView()
private let contentContainer = UIView()
private let collectionViewController = CollectionViewController()

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    scrollView.delegate = self

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "burger")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    let imageContainer = UIView()
    imageContainer.backgroundColor = .darkGray

    contentContainer.backgroundColor = .clear

    let textBacking = UIView()
    textBacking.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1235740449, blue: 0.2699040081, alpha: 1)

    view.addSubview(scrollView)

    scrollView.addSubview(imageContainer)
    scrollView.addSubview(textBacking)
    scrollView.addSubview(contentContainer)
    scrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    self.addChild(collectionViewController)
    contentContainer.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)
    collectionViewController.didMove(toParent: self)


    scrollView.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.edges.equalTo(view)
    }

    imageContainer.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.top.equalTo(scrollView)
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.height.equalTo(imageContainer.snp.width).multipliedBy(0.7)
    }

    imageView.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.left.right.equalTo(imageContainer)

        //** Note the priorities
        make.top.equalTo(view).priority(.high)

        //** We add a height constraint too
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(imageContainer.snp.height).priority(.required)

        //** And keep the bottom constraint
        make.bottom.equalTo(imageContainer.snp.bottom)
    }

    contentContainer.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.top.equalTo(imageContainer.snp.bottom)
        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView)
    }

    textBacking.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(contentContainer)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view)
    }

    collectionViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints {
        make in

        make.left.right.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(contentContainer)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view)
    }

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = view.safeAreaInsets
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, right: 0)
}

//MARK: - Scroll View Delegate

private var previousStatusBarHidden = false

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if previousStatusBarHidden != shouldHideStatusBar {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        })

        previousStatusBarHidden = shouldHideStatusBar
    }
}

//MARK: - Status Bar Appearance

override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return shouldHideStatusBar
}

private var shouldHideStatusBar: Bool {
    let frame = contentContainer.convert(contentContainer.bounds, to: nil)
    return frame.minY < view.safeAreaInsets.top
}

}
```

Everything is the same as in this file: https://github.com/TwoLivesLeft/StretchyLayout/blob/Step-6/StretchyLayouts/StretchyViewController.swift with the exception of the `innerText` being replaced by my `CollectionViewController`.

As you can see, the `UICollectionView` is displayed properly - however I am unable to scroll up or down anymore. I'm not sure where my mistake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are constraining the size of your collection view to fit within the bounds of the parent view containing the collection view's container view and the image view. As a result, the container `scrollView` has no `contentSize` to scroll over, and that's why you can't scroll. You need to ensure your collection view's content size is reflected in the parent scroll view's content size.

In the example you gave, this behavior was achieved by the length of the label requiring a height greater than the height between the image view and the rest of the view. In your case, the collection view container needs to behave as if it's larger than that area.

*Edit:* More precisely you need to pass the `collectionView.contentSize` up to your `scrollView.contentSize`. A scrollview's `contentSize` is settable, so you just need to increase the `scrollView.contentSize` by the `collectionView.contentSize` - `collectionView.height` (since your scrollView's current `contentSize` currently includes the collectionView's height). I'm not sure how you are adding your child view controller, but at the point you do that, I would increment your scrollView's contentSize accordingly. If your collectionView's size changes after that, though, you'll also need to ensure you delegate that change up to your `scrollView`. This could be accomplished by having a protocol such as:

```
protocol InnerCollectionViewHeightUpdated {
  func collectionViewContentHeightChanged(newSize: CGSize)
}
```

and then making the controller containing the `scrollView` implement this protocol and update the `scrollView` `contentSize` accordingly. From your `collectionView` child controller, you would have a `delegate` property for this protocol (set this when creating the child view controller, setting the delegate as `self`, the controller containing the child VC and also the `scrollView`). Then whenever the `collectionView` height changes (if you add cells, for example) you can do `delegate.collectionViewContentHeightChanged(...` to ensure your scroll behavior will continue to function.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - could you post a short code snippet on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Alk I've added a bunch more info, with a bit of code, it's a bit more nuanced than a simple code sample can achieve, but let me know if that still didn't clarify :)

Comment: So I've added the following code: `scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width + collectionViewController.collectionView.contentSize.width , height: collectionViewController.collectionView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentSize.height - collectionViewController.collectionView.frame.height)` right after `contentContainer.addSubview(collectionViewController.view)` but it doesn't seem to change anything

Comment: It's going to be more subtle than just adding those lines. Those lines look incorrect regardless, unless you're also looking for scrollability left/right, which I don't think is your goal. You only want to add to the height, the width should remain constant. You also need to ensure that your collectionView's height is correct when getting it, which it probably is not before even being added as a subview (it hasn't had a chance to lay out yet...).

Comment: also, you see how in the example when they use the `innerText` label they just use `make.edges.equalTo(textContainer).inset(14)` as the constraint - when I try this the `collectionView` doesn't appear on the screen, and instead I have to use these constraints to make it show up `make.top.equalTo(imageContainer.snp.bottom) make.left.right.equalTo(view) make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView)`

Comment: ok this works when I execute the code after a couple second delay - obviously that's not an ideal solution. Is there a lifecycle method in which I can be sure that the collectionView is done laying out?

Comment: Check out `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, that's likely your best bet in this situation :)

Comment: Thanks! Also, any idea why the collectionView doesn't show up when `make.edges.equalTo(textContainer).inset(14)` is used

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how `Snapkit` works, and looks like something going on with that. Sorry but I haven't used `Snapkit` myself so I have no clue why that wouldn't work

Comment: same tbh, thanks either way though, you've fixed the main issue! :)